# FSC : error FS0078: Unable to find the file. How to ensure the .dll gets copied over?

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2022

I'm developing F# projects (fsproj) in Visual Studio 2022.
I intermittently get a compile error

```
>------ Build started: Project: MyProject, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.302\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.MvcApplicationPartsDiscovery.targets(54,5): warning RAZORSDK1007: Reference assembly C:\Users\Diana\repository\library\bin\Debug\net6.0\library.dll could not be found. This is typically caused by build errors in referenced projects.
5>FSC : error FS0078: Unable to find the file 'C:\Users\Diana\repository\library\bin\Debug\net6.0\library.dll' in any of C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.7\ref\net6.0 C:\Users\repository\project\src\MyProject\MyProject C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.302\FSharp\
```

The library is indeed not present in any of the searched locations. This suggests that I have something in my fsproj files misconfigured.
How do I ensure that library.dll is copied to the bin directory of MyProject?

Note for completeness: library.dll is not a NuGet package, it is a dll that is built from a local .csproj file that is part of the Solution (.sln)

Edit: CopyLocal is set to true for all Project References

Comment: Do you reference the dll directly from your project 'MyProject' or do you reference the C# project? If the latter, the dll should be copied automatically at build time and you should not have to set up any copying settings.

Comment: I've used Project References. I come from a C# background so grappling a bit with F# currently..

Comment: In Solution Explorer, in the Dependencies of your F# project, right click, Add Project Reference, select the C# project from Projects.

Comment: I had already done that when I created this question